# NASA's RS-25 Engines

Tags: nasa, engines, sls, ssme

I am developing a FSX-based space flight simulator [FSX SpacePort](http://www.terrabuilder.com). I've been trying to get the detailed specs on NASA's RS-25 engine, namely, what were the ramp-up times for this engine? As in, how long did it take from ignition to full thrust?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good assumption is that the startup sequence is very similar to the SSME. Here is some SSME startup data showing the time you asked about from the [Rocketdyne Pocket Data Book](https://archive.org/details/PocketDataRIRD87142SpaceShuttleMainEngine/page/n39).  Eventually the SLS will be using RS-25Es which are somewhat different from the SSME, but my guess is that the start sequence won't change much if at all.

[image]

The hashed field is test experience, the solid lines are the ICD requirements.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @Mitch99 Since you're new to the site: If this answer is what you were looking for, please mark it as correct by clicking the gray checkmark beside it.  And upvote if you have a mind to.

Comment: Got it, thanks!!

Comment: So - since it takes ~4 seconds to get them to 100% thrust, do they then ignite them at T -4:00 seconds, and they count T -0:00 the time all of them are roughly at 100%, the SRBs get lit, and it's a "mission start"?

Comment: I only know about shuttle, but there the start command was send at ~T-5 seconds, which gave time for the SSMEs to light, the "twang" to settle, and then the SRBs lit at, yes, T-0.  SLS won't have the "twang" to deal with because its engines are axially mounted.

Comment: How long after SRB light are the hold-downs fired?

Comment: @RussellBorogove The SRB igniters and the charges that blow the nuts on the hold down posts were fired simo. https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/shutref/srb/ignition.html

Comment: @OrganicMarble Wow -- I guess they had a lot of confidence in the consistency of the initial thrust curve for the SRBs.

Comment: @OrganicMarble,  "Twang" - I am assuming, oscillation due to their off-longitudinal axis orientation?
Also - would you know about the ramp-down rates? As in, how long did it take to thrust down from 100% down to 0%?

Comment: Shutdown is a bit more complex because you don't always start from the same power level. If you'd like to ask a new question, I can dig up some info.

Comment: Just to clarify - is the y-axis 'percent of rated power level'? I'm having a hard time reading it!

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Mitch99 as a side-note, while it's good to mark an answer as "accepted" if the answer provided is a perfect match, it can also dissuade additional answers. If the answer you got didn't fully answer your question, wait a little bit before accepting it as others may still give a more complete answer, or an answer to supplement the original. (This obviously doesn't apply here as Mr. Marble's answer was great).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn you are correct of course, but the one time - *the one time* - that Johnny Robinson actually accepted one of my answers, you posted this, he took off the acceptance, and never accepted another one.  *sigh*

Comment: @OrganicMarble oh-- Maybe it'd be better to not say that then, I can remove it :). It was the standard on my other site though codegolf.stackexchange.com. Even I struggle to remember to mark answers as accepted and often have to go back to do it in large batches. I'd never "unaccept" an answer though, that's slightly rude.

Comment: No, I'm not bitter. Not at all! Ha ha! Seriously, you are absolutely right.

Comment: And, it wasn't even you @MagicOctopusUrn who did it. It was "Bear". So please accept my apologies.

Comment: @OrganicMarble not a biologist eh-- if you can't tell a bear and an octopus apart ;P? Nothing to apologize for-- sounded like something I'd do hah.